# How to add a step function within a dictionary macro

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I am new to VBA and I have been using the great help within this site, to create a macro to take a list of numbers from one sheet (Sheet 14), remove the duplicates and paste within another sheet (Sheet 2).

I am hoping to take this further by rather than pasting the cells one after another I am looking to have the list pasted in alternate rows i.e D10, D12, D14 etc.

I have tried various methods from within this site, however to no avail. I have used different types of "Step" functions but I am struggling to incorporate this within the below coding.

Any help is much appreciated!

Below is what I have at the moment:

```
Sub RUN()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dictionary As Object
    Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Sheet14.Activate
    lastRow = Sheet14.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 3 To lastRow
    If Len(Cells(i, "F")) <> 0 Then
        dictionary.Add Cells(i, "F").Value, 1
    End If
Next

    Sheet2.Range("d10").Resize(dictionary.Count).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(dictionary.keys)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox dictionary.Count & " RUN TEMPLATES."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach (BTW, I wouldn't call a macro RUN):

```
Sub ListUniques()

    Dim lastRow               As Long
    Dim i                     As Long
    Dim dictionary            As Object
    Dim vKeys

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With Sheet14

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastRow
        If Len(.Cells(i, "F")) <> 0 Then
            dictionary(.Cells(i, "F").Value) = 1
        End If
    Next
    End With

    vKeys = dictionary.keys
    For i = LBound(vKeys) To UBound(vKeys)
        Sheet2.Range("d10").Offset(2 * i).Value = vKeys(i)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox dictionary.Count & " RUN TEMPLATES."

End Sub
```

Comment: Rory - Thank you, that worked a treat! I have spent the last week trying to figure this out!